# How to login into a page without id on puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, automation, puppeteer

I'm trying to login to Discord using puppeteer but there isn't an id on the page. I'm not sure what to do about this and I tried using different selectors but it didn't work.

```
(async () => {
  var email = 'email@email.com'
  var password = 'password'
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://discordapp.com/login');
  await page.type('#email', email)
  await page.type('#password', password)
})();
```

Comment: provide the html , u can use attributes like name/class/type  as selector

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how puppeteer selectors work. but based on javascript selectors these two worked just fine:

For the password field:

```
input[type=password]
```

For the email field:

```
input[type=email]
```